# How to efficiently access vertex_handle from CGAL::Triangulation_3 for a vertex in a std::list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, cgal

I am working on an algorithm for *mesh generation* in which I need to maintain a collection of vertices,segments and triangles in a structure called *Piecwise Linear Complex*(PLC) and a *Delaunay tetrahedralization*(DT)(extension of Delaunay triangulation to 3D space) of vertices in PLC.

As per the algorithm, I frequently need to get a handle to a vertex in DT while I have pointer to the same vertex(both have *same* x,y,z coordinates) in PLC. Below is the initialization of DT and structure of PLC:

PLC structure:

```
class vertex
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    std::list<vertex*> neighbor_vertices;
};

class segment
{
    vertex* endpoints[2];
};

class facet
{
    vertex*vertices[3]; 
};

class PLC
{
    std::list<vertex> vertex_list;
    std::list<segment> segment_list;
    std::list<facet> facet_list;
};
```

Initialization of DT:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<> tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<K,tds> Delaunay;

Delaunay DT; 
PLC input_constraints; 

// Initializing Delaunay tetrahedralization structure
DT.insert(input_constraints.vertex_list.begin(),input_constraints.vertex_list.end());
```

My question is:

For the problem of getting `vertex_handle` in `DT` corresponding to a `vertex` in `input_constraints`, is there any more *efficient*(requiring lesser number of operations) approach than:

1. Simply traversing all vertices of `DT` and comparing their x,y,z components with that of a `vertex` in `input_constraints`.
2. Maintaining a mapping between `vertex_handle` of `DT` and `vertex` in `input_constraints`.

This problem can turnout to be a bottleneck because I need to perform this operation frequently and `DT` and `input_constraints` both keep updating at different stages of the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you should try to avoid loosing the information, that is, maintain a `list<Vertex_handle>` instead of a `list<Vertex *>`.

There is a way to do what you need, though.  Something like the following might work :

```
Vertex * vp; // your vertex pointer
Vertex_handle v = Delaunay::Triangulation_data_structure::Vertex_range::s_iterator_to(*vp);
```